# Installing and Upgrading Java on Linux / CentOS without prompts

Tags: java, linux, installation, centos

I have the scripts below to download, install or update Java on Linux OS such as CentOS.
Is there anything better than that around? It is a quite cumbersome script and I'd like a more elegant solution.

```
###INSTALL 
wget http://www.java.net/download/jdk7/binaries/jdk-7-ea-bin-b96-linux-x64-03_jun_2010.bin  
chmod a+x jdk-7-ea-bin-b96-linux-x64-03_jun_2010.bin  
echo y > answers.txt  
./jdk-7-ea-bin-b96-linux-x64-03_jun_2010.bin < answers.txt &>/dev/null  
mkdir /jdk7  
mv /root/jdk1.7.0 /jdk7  
ln -sf /jdk7/bin/java /usr/bin/java  
rm -f jdk-7-ea-bin-b96-linux-x64-03_jun_2010.bin  


###UPGRADE  
wget http://www.java.net/download/jdk7/binaries/jdk-7-ea-bin-b117-linux-x64-04_nov_2010.bin  
chmod a+x jdk-7-ea-bin-b117-linux-x64-04_nov_2010.bin  
echo y > answers.txt  
rm -rf /jdk7  
./jdk-7-ea-bin-b96-linux-x64-03_jun_2010.bin < answers.txt &>/dev/null  
mv /root/jdk1.7.0 /jdk7  
ln -sf /jdk7/bin/java /usr/bin/java  
rm -f jdk-7-ea-bin-b96-linux-x64-03_jun_2010.bin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "improvement" can be using `yes` instead of `echo y >answers.txt` and `...< answers.txt`.

It may worth to check if an update is available using the next number from current `0X` (in case if oracle won't change distr naming convention) and then download and install it. But I'm not sure it really worths.